# Conditional Display of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to display something conditionally in html.
If a person is logged in, he should see the logout button, if he isn't logged in, he should see a register and login button. 
To see if a person is logged in, I've defined an html5 localStorage.

My idea was to do a javascript function being called in the `<body onload="function()">`
In this javascript was an if instruction which switches between

```
document.getElementById("Item1").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("IdOne").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

This does work, but it loads very very slowly.
Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use session variables to do that

Comment: You will need some kind of programming language, like session variables and PHP.

Comment: Javascript is not enough and despite being possible, hiding content through CSS/DOM manipulation isn't safe. Right click -> inspect source -> display whatever the hell i want

Comment: There's nothing wrong with conditionally displaying a login/logout button in javascript.  That's not what needs to be secured server-side.  What needs to be secured server-side is content that never should go to a non-logged-in person.

Comment: I can't use php, because I've to use jetty.
How do I hide it via Servlet?

Comment: For Java servlets, you'd typically use [JAAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Authentication_and_Authorization_Service) to log the user in, then in your Java servlet, test whether you have a valid Principal or not and send HTML and CSS accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it in PHP
    http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions.htm

This is how you can do it in ASP.net
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I'd add: "And basically you DO NOT DO it with javascript"

Answer (score 0):

Use a programming language such as `PHP`. But you'll need to manage `sessions` :)